# Cordova windows app ajax requests to HTTPS fail with connectivity failure

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I am newbie in cordova.  I have make the self signed https request through ajax. I am not able to connect the server. I am getting in connectivity failure in windows app. so I have tried some other some other signed certificate its working fine. I am using latest cordova version. so I have added latest plugin for whitelist cordova-plugin-whitelist. but in android and ios it working fine. but same things I have used in windows platform its getting fails connectivity failure. so problem I am not able to make self signed https reuqest in wp8 platform?? pls any one help for this I have struggled lot??

Answer (score 0):

For https connexion to work, you have to trust the certificate on the server.
If the server certificate is not known by the client, the call fails because the client can't authenticate the server.

Browsers and OSs have a truststore with all the trusted certificates.

If you use a self signed certificate, you have to install it either in the system or in the browser. For windows phone, I don't konw it it's in the system settings of in the IE settings.

And your self-signed certificate must also be valid for the domain or ip you use to contact the server.

You could also use free SSL certificate like https://letsencrypt.org/ instead of your self-signed certificate.